# Problems serializing JSON data using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, http

I am trying to use RestTemplate to serialize JSON data from one of our API's, via a GET call.

It's as if the getForObject method is expecting an XML value in the API URL when really it's a JSON response.  From all the searching I've done this method should be expecting JSON, not XML - so what is wrong?

Any help is really appreciated.

Controller

```
RestTemplate appApi = new RestTemplate();
Application app = appApi.getForObject("api url", Application.class);
```

Application

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Application {
    ApplicationDetails value;

    @Data
    public class ApplicationDetails {
        String salsaId;
        String itSystemName;
        String businessOwner;
        String businessOwnershipLob;
        String leadProgramme;
        String lifecycleStage;
    }
}
```

An example of the response 'API URL' will give:

```
{
  "value": {
    "salsaId": "data",
    "itSystemName": "data",
    "businessOwner": "data",
    "businessOwnershipLob": "data",
    "leadProgramme": "data",
    "lifecycleStage": "data"
  }
}
```

From my view this should all work perfectly, and the response from that api call should be held in Application object 'app'.  However, when running I get the following error:

```
2019-02-12 15:36:47.644 ERROR 864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.***.tools.***.models.Application] and content type [application/xml;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]] with root cause

com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

Comment: Edit: I saw you had noticed the xml thing yourself. Maybe the content-type headers in the response are set to application/xml?

Comment: try this  `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity<Application> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Application.class);
`

Comment: @dkb Thanks, I gave that a try and it does seems to 'work', but its not exactly what I was trying to do.  I was hoping I could serialize the json and put it straight into an Application object, rather than a response entity.

Comment: @dkb I tried using those headers and adding them as an parameter to the getForObject method, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: you can not add headers if you are using `getForObject()` method: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-

Comment: @dkb Regarding your first point, I looked on the receiving API's swagger, and it seems the response type is simply text/plain.  So not, XML unfortunately (or that would 100% have been the problem )

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I assumed you could since I wasn't getting any compilation or IDE errors.

Comment: Set MediaType as text and give it a try.